# Eclipse's DDMS is not detecting device (Emulator)

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator

I am using Ubuntu (Linux) machine. DDMS in my eclipse is not detecting Emulator (Gingerbread) as devices.
Gingerbread emulator is working fine. When I run "ddms" in cammand prompt, its working properly, it will launch ddms which will show emulator as device with running processes BUT when I try to do the same in Eclipse its not detecting.

Because of that I am not able to do debugging.

Please help.

Regards
Rke

Comment: In ddms mode, select the device from left-top corner......I think you'll get the device for debugging.

Comment: Its not showing any device in DDMS mode, even though emulator is running....

Comment: I'm not using DDMS and Eclipse at same time. There is some interference between them. Sometime when I run emulator, it is not visible for adb, after restart of emulator it is ok. Usually if emulator is starting too long, it is not connected. I'm using windows for development.

Comment: Restart your emulator and try again

Comment: in eclipse only there is Window>open perspective > DDMS there you should see devices tab in top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

you have to start the adb server to get the service of the emulator or any device, if you using ubuntu then you have to kill the adb server and start it again, then it will work fine